# Api call not firing up in redux action with debouce

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, debouncing

Im trying to implement debouncing with my own pure js function for calling the action in action file with axios POST request.

The below code in the input box component

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { searchDrug } from '../../actions/drug-interaction'

function CustomInputSearch(props) {
  const { handleSelectInput } = props


  const apiCall = (value) => {
    searchDrug(value)
    
}

  const debounce = (apiFunc, delay) => {
    let inDebounce
    return function () {
      const context = this
      const args = arguments 
      clearTimeout(inDebounce)
      inDebounce = setTimeout(() => apiFunc.apply(context, args), delay)
    }
  }

  const optimizedVersion = debounce(apiCall, 500)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    optimizedVersion(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className='form-control'
        placeholder='Search Drug...'
        onKeyUp={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomInputSearch
```

Ignore the unnececssary imports.

The below code is the action file.

```
export const searchDrug = (drug) => {
    const params = {
        "start": drug,
        "limit": 100
    }
    let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    }
    return  (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DRUG_LIST_NOTIFY', payload: { drugListLoading: true } })
         axios.post(`${API_URL}/drug/autocomplete`, params, axiosConfig)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'DRUG_LIST',
                    payload: { response: response.data, drugListLoading: false }
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'DRUG_LIST_NOTIFY', payload: { drugListLoading: false } })
                if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
                    window.open('/?src=auth-error', '_self')
                }
            });
    };
}
```

But im not seeing any request going in network tab in browser.Im also composedWithDevtools in redux store.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `searchDrug` action must be came from `dispatch` instead of calling it directly.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { searchDrug } from '../../actions/drug-interaction'

function CustomInputSearch(props) {
  const { handleSelectInput } = props
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const apiCall = (value) => {
    dispatch(searchDrug(value))
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks man, made my day, since we were using both functional and class components in the same project, confuses a lot.